# CSS -webkit-mask-position only responding to one animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I am having some trouble animating the x and y position of a mask.

1) The mask is a wave and is of type black on transparent background.
2) Either the x or the y are able to be animated just not working together

Not 100% what I am doing wrong, I have searched Stack Overflow for a resolution but as of yet I havent turned anything up.

The following is the css that is causing issue:

```
    #middle{
      display: block;
      -webkit-mask-image: url("waveMask3.png");
      -webkit-mask-position-x: 100px;
      -webkit-mask-position-y: var(--yPos);
      animation: waveX 3s linear forwards infinite, waveY 3s linear forwards infinite;
    }

    @keyframes waveX{
        0%{
            -webkit-mask-position-x:100px;

        }
        50%{
            -webkit-mask-position-x:-900px;

        }
        100%{
            -webkit-mask-position-x:-900px;

        }
    }
    @keyframes waveY{
        0%{
            -webkit-mask-position-y: var(--yPos);
        }
        50%{
            -webkit-mask-position-y:calc(var(--yPos) - 10px);

        }
        100%{
            -webkit-mask-position-y:calc(var(--yPos) - 10px);

        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: are you defining the variable? .. it's working fine for me. Also note that the animation of the Y axis is unoticeable compared to the X one, you are only changing 10px

Comment: Yeah the varaible is set at :root....the y shouldnt be that noticeable compared to x as its filling a div slowly over time...

Comment: here is a working code: https://jsfiddle.net/o4gubd9v/

Comment: hmmm that is weird.

Comment: I found the problem thanks for confirming it was working. Turns out I was looking at the top edge of the mask which is a straight line lmao...thanks Temani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with an issue where they are pretty sure that their code is right but the animation on their mask is not giving the expected results; make sure that

1). The masks is covering the correct part. Black shows,transparency hides.
2). Make sure that your mask is the correct size and orientation to show the animation. My problem was that my wave was on the bottom edge of my mask when it need to be on the top edge.

This resolved the issue for me...I was able to see this by giving the container a background color and by setting width, height and position.